# Wayland session not available in Fedora VM?

Tags: fedora, gnome

I've tried Fedora 24 Beta Workstation both in VM (Virtual Box) and on bare metal. Only instance running directly on my machine offered a Wayland session. Why is Wayland not offered in VM?

Illustrative [screenshot](http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Install-GUI-in-Arch-Linux-14-600x450.jpg): Available sessions are offered after clicking on gear icon next to Sign in button on login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wayland [needs to be supported](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-Rawhide-Wayland) by the video driver. At the moment only some open source drivers included in the kernel have support.